# aura:iteration label of current field

Tags: lightning, aura-iteration, iteration

Is there a possibility to get the Label of current field using aura:iteration ?

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.objectName}" var="objectName"> 
     <lightning:input value="{!objectName.field1}" label="{!objectName.field1.Name}"/> 
     ....
</aura:iteration>
```

I checked the variations like `label="{!objectName.field1.Name}"` and `label="{!objectName.field1.Label}"`.

I add that the field values display correctly.

Comment: AFAIK not without you building something yourself - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cNLeQAM.

Comment: You can get label/value if you add on change event for your lightning:input